# Regex to exclude match based on string before first forward slash

Tags: regex

I want any path string that leads to a file with an extension of '.log' or a path that contains the directory 'tmp' to be excluded from the match

I'm nearly there:

```
(?!tmp).+?\.(?!log|tmp).+
```

http://rubular.com/r/Ubkz7MIEGH

What I want is for

tmp/hello.jpg

to be excluded in the same way that

```
hello.log
hmm.tmp
```

Are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
^(?!(?:.*log$)|tmp).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(?!.*\btmp\b)(?!.+\.log\b)(.+)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?!.*\btmp\b)(?!.+\.log\b)(.+)$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    tmp                      'tmp'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    log                      'log'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!tmp).*(?<!\.tmp|log)$
```

It's just a negative lookbehind. [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/tG3hZ2)